# DirectX 11 Vertices Coordinates

Tags: c++, directx, coordinates, directx-11, vertices

I'm working on my first C++ and DirectX 11 project where my current goal is to draw a colored triangle on the screen. This has worked well without any problems. However, there's one part that I would like to change, but I don't know how. I've tried searching for a solution but I havn't found any yet, and I guess that the reason is because I don't really know what I should search for.

Currently I set up my triangles 3 vertices like this:

```
VertexPos vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3(  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f )},
    { XMFLOAT3(  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f )},
    { XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f )},
}
```

Where VertexPos is defined like this:

```
struct VertexPos
{
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
};
```

Currenty, my vertices position is set up by the range -1.0F to 1.0F, where 0.0F is the center. How can I change this so that I can position my vertices by using "real" coordinates like this:

```
VertexPos vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3(  100.0f,  300.0f, 1.0f )},
    { XMFLOAT3(  200.0f,  200.0f, 1.0f )},
    { XMFLOAT3(  200.0f,  300.0f, 1.0f )},
}
```

Comment: You have to setup an appropriate projection matrix and multiply the coordinates with the matrix in the vertex shader. If you're just beginning, go through some more tutorials and you'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usual way:

   - create orthogonal projection matrix ([`XMMatrixOrthographicLH()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixorthographiclh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you using XMMATH)
   - create constant buffer with this matrix on CPU side (C++ code) and on GPU size (vertex shader)
   - multiply vertex positions by orthogonal projection matrix in vertex shader
2. Simpler way (from F.Luna book):

   ```
   XMFLOAT3 SpriteBatch::PointToNdc(int x, int y, float z)
   {
       XMFLOAT3 p;

       p.x = 2.0f*(float)x/mScreenWidth - 1.0f;
       p.y = 1.0f - 2.0f*(float)y/mScreenHeight;
       p.z = z;

       return p;
   }
   ```

   Almost the same, but on CPU side. Of course, you can move this code to shader too.

P.S. Probably your book/manual/tutorials will learn you about it a little later. So, you better trust it and flow step-by step.

Happy coding! =)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Drop.

I understand. The reason I got confused is because I've done a tutorial in DirectX 9 some months ago, and then it was possible to do like this:

`struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z, rhw;
    DWORD color;
}`

`CUSTOMVERTEX OurVertices[] =
{
    {320.0f, 50.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255),},
    {520.0f, 400.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0),},
    {120.0f, 400.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0),},
};`

So have they removed this feature from DirectX 11? If yes, why?

EDIT: Hmm, sorry, but code tags doesn't work :/

Comment: Yep, fixed function pipeline, and pre-transformed vertex declarations, not exists any more. Now you must write your own shader programs and transform vertices in them as you wish. Why? Well, I don't know the answer. Probably, because it was not needed for most developers, and inclusion of this in new API would made it more difficult to implement.

Comment: Is there a great performance benefit from doing it using the second method instead of doing it using the first method?

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 Standard answer: it depends. On many factors. To be sure, you really need to try several approaches, profile and compare them. At first glance, it seems that you save some multiplications by using function like `PointToNdc`. But, probably, "classic" vector-matrix SIMD-optimized multiplications will be faster. Hard to say, really. Anyway, it is unlikely that you will hit performance bottleneck here unless you drawing many objects with orthographic projection.